# Dynamically change query params Angular unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-activatedroute

I have a component that has 2 different states dependent on the query params provided.
Here's the 2 query param states:

```
  const mockLocalQueryParams = {
    Id: Guid.create(),
    customerId: Guid.create(),
  };

  const mockOrganicQueryParams = {
    id1: Guid.create(),
    id2: Guid.create(),
    id3: 1,
    id4: 2,
  };
```

I'm using `mockLocalQueryParams` as the default state but I want to change to `mockOrganicQueryParams` so I can test functionality for that state also

```
beforeEach(
  waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            queryParams: of(mockLocalQueryParams),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  })
);
```

I've tried creating a new `describe` block and `TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute).snapshot.params = of(mockOrganicQueryParams)` and other similar things but this undefined.

How can I change the query params for when I want to test `mockOrganicQueryParams` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way in my opinion is to do it through a `BehaviorSubject` that you can have a handle on. Something like this:

```
// !! create a behavior subject here so you can have a handle on it
const mockQueryParams = new BehaviorSubject<any>(mockLocalQueryParams);
beforeEach(
  waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
           // !! assign the query params as an observable here
            queryParams: mockQueryParams.asObservable(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  })
);
```

Whenever you want to change the `queryParams` subscription, you can just do `mockQueryParams.next(mockOrganicQueryParams);`